# Linq FirstOrDefault logic

Tags: c#, linq

IN a method I have, I am trying to set an item Tinder into a fire pit and start the fire when I click on it. The problem I'm having is that if I have more than one tinder in my inventory, the fire won't light. If I light another fire first and I still have Tinder in my inventory, then the fire will light. I can't think of any reason why this is happening except for the second line where I am using FirstOrDefault.

```
    private void StartFire()
    {
        MouseState currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();

        //if player has more than one tinder in the inventory the fire won't start with click unless other fire is lit first

        if (player.NextToFirePit == true)
        {
            Item firestarter = player.PlayerInventory.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemName == "firestarter");
            if (firestarter != null)
            {
                Item firepitwithtinder = allItemsOnGround.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemName == "firepitwithtinder" && i.ItemRectangle.Contains(MouseWorldPosition));
                if (firepitwithtinder != null && currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && oldMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
                {
                    Fire fire = new Fire(new Vector2(firepitwithtinder.Position.X + (firepitwithtinder.Texture.Width / 2), firepitwithtinder.Position.Y + (firepitwithtinder.Texture.Height / 2)));
                    fire.FirePit = firepitwithtinder;

                    Fires.Add(fire);
                    player.PlayerLevelSystem.UpdateSkills(10, "firemaking");
                    firepitwithtinder.ItemName = "firepitwithfire";
                } oldMouseState = currentMouseState;
            }
        } 
    }
```

Am I not using FirstOrDefault right in this case? Setting the tinder in the fire works fine, so I don't think that method is the problem.

Comment: What's the expected behaviour?

Comment: No matter how many tinder you have in your inventory, you click the fire pit and it starts a fire and removes 1 tinder.

Comment: What is the Item, post declaration.

Comment: Do you remove the item `firestarter` from your inventory list when it reaches 0?

Comment: It's hard to see exactly what you're doing. I would split up the multiple condition if-statements and see exactly where it fails. The only thing I can see that _might_ be a problem is this: `i.ItemRectangle.Contains(MouseWorldPosition)`.